# In a potetiometer experiment when finding the internal resistance of a Dry Cell (not Leclanché), why is the internal resistance varied?

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image: circuit diagram. The cell 'E' is the one whose internal resistance is to be found out]In **potentiometer**,my internal resistance is coming out to be different for different values of **SHUNT** used.

I've tired it many times and each time, the internal resistance seems to be increasing gradually with each reading. Is it due to the heating effects ?

Comment: Are we talking about the internal resistance of the battery, or of the potentiometer? A drawing of your circuit would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you measure the potential difference across the terminals of a battery $v$ and the current passing through the battery $i$ you get a relationship between the potential difference and the current as shown in the graph below:

[image]

For the straight lien part of the graph you can write the equation $v = \mathcal E - r i$  where $\mathcal E$ ids the emf of the battery and $r$ is called the internal resistance of the battery although there is no actual resistor inside the battery.

The internal resistance is a measure of the opposition to current flow presented by the constituent parts of the battery.

However when a battery delivers current those constituent parts can change.
For small current the change is relatively small and so the internal resistance of the battery stay roughly constant as shown by the straight line part of the graph.

However if the current is delivered for a period of time and also large then the constituent parts of the battery change and this invariably makes the graph steeper (in the negative sense) which can be interpreted as an increase in the internal resistance of the battery.
This effect will occur at lower currents if the battery is old.

So in your experiment before you get to the balance point the battery is delivering current, its constituent parts are changing, which in turn increase the internal resistance of the battery.

You will find that if you take a reading, then disconnect the battery from the circuit and give it time to "recover", change its constituent parts back to what was there originally, and then repeat the reading you might well find the the internal resistance has changed (decreased?).

This increase in internal resistance shows itself in a torch battery in that the bulb gets dimmer if the torch is left on.  The switching the torch off, waiting, and then w=switching the torch on again will initially produces a brighter beam of light.

The changes in the constituent parts of batteries are due polarisation where the chemical reaction within the battery progresses so fast that hydrogen is produced on the negative electrode thus decreasing the effectiveness of the battery by increasing its internal resistance.
The battery will have chemicals called depolarizers in it to prevent the formation of hydrogen gas but if the current is too high the depolarizer cannot cope and hydrogen is produced.

There is much more about primary (non-rechargeable) cells on the Internet and here is the [link to the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_cell).